# Program to email you exchange rates that you are tracking and stats on them

Tags: python, email, finance, scheduled-tasks

This is a program I made as I am currently living in Japan with a British bank account, so exchange rates matter to me.

On the first time run, you run the script with two arguments (two currencies) and it will track those currencies. You can add as many exchange rate trackers as you like.

It emails you daily (automated via crontabs, which at the moment have to be added manually) with the current rates that you are tracking along with how long if has been increasing/decreasing/stable for.

All critique and comments are greatly appreciated.

reporting.py

```
"""
currency_report.reporting

This module grabs exchange rates, writes CurrencyTracker
objects to a file and emails a report to the given email.
"""

import sys
import os.path
import urllib.request
import datetime
import decimal
import utils


def main():
    FILE_NAME = 'rates_to_watch.pkl'
    EMAIL = ''
    PASSWORD = ''

    arg_count = len(sys.argv)

    # Load trackers and record new rates to them.
    if arg_count == 1:

        # Check if tracking file exists.
        if os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME):
            rates_to_watch = utils.read_file(FILE_NAME)

            for rate in rates_to_watch:
                rate.add_rate(grab_rate(rate.get_currencies()))
                utils.write_file(FILE_NAME, rates_to_watch)

            report = generate_report(rates_to_watch)
            utils.send_email('Exchange Rate Report', report,
                                             EMAIL, EMAIL, PASSWORD)

        # Tracking file doesn't exist, tell user to add trackers.
        else:
            print("Error: No currencies are being tracked.")
            print("Please run the following command:")
            print("python currency_report.py CURRENCY1 CURRENCY2")
            print("eg. python currency_report.py GBP JPY")

    # Create new currency tracker.
    elif arg_count == 3:
        __, currency_1, currency_2 = sys.argv
        valid_currencies = open('currencies.txt').read()

        # Check if currencies are valid.
        if currency_1 in valid_currencies and currency_1 in valid_currencies:
            currencies = (currency_1, currency_2)
            new_tracker = trackers.CurrencyTracker(currencies,
                                                  grab_rate(currencies))

            # Edit existing tracker file.
            if os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME):
                rates_to_watch = utils.read_file(FILE_NAME)
                rates_to_watch.append(new_tracker)
                utils.write_file(FILE_NAME, rates_to_watch)

            # Create new tracker file.
            else:
                rates_to_watch = [new_tracker]
                utils.write_file(FILE_NAME, rates_to_watch)
        else:
            print("Error: Invalid currency codes.")
    else:
        print("Error: Invalid number of arguments. {count}"
              "argument(s).".format(count=arg_count))


def grab_rate(currencies):
    """Grabs exchange rate from Yahoo Finance.

    :param currencies: A tuple containing the currencies to get the
    rare for.
    """

    currency_1, currency_2 = currencies

    # Build request url.
    url_template = ('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=l1&'
                    's={cur1}{cur2}=X')
    url = url_template.format(cur1=currency_1, cur2=currency_2)

    # Grab data from url.
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    rate = (datetime.datetime.now(), decimal.Decimal(data[:-1]))

    print("Current rate: {rate}".format(rate=str(rate[1])))

    return rate


def generate_report(rates_to_watch):
    """ Generates a report on tracked rates and emails them.

    :param rates_to_watch: A list of CurrencyTrackers.
    :param email: The email to send report to.
    :param password: The password for the email account.
    """

    # Create email report.
    complete_report = ""

    for rate in rates_to_watch:
        cur_rate = rate.get_current_rate()[1]
        streak_dir, streak_mag = rate.get_streak()

        one_report = """
        ----{currencies}----
        Rate: {rate}
        10: {x10}
        100: {x100}
        1,000: {x1000}
        10,000: {x10000}
        \n
        """.format(currencies=rate.get_currencies(), rate=cur_rate,
                   x10=cur_rate * 10, x100=cur_rate * 100,
                   x1000=cur_rate * 1000, x10000=cur_rate * 10000)

        if streak_dir > 0:
            streak_report = ("This exchange rate has been increasing for"
                             "{count} day(s).\n").format(count=streak_mag)
        elif streak_dir < 0:
            streak_report = ("This exchange rate has been decreasing for"
                             "{count} day(s).\n").format(count=streak_mag)
        else:
            streak_report = ("This exchange rate has been stable for {count}"
                             "day(s).\n)").format(count=streak_mag)

        one_report += streak_report
        complete_report += one_report

    return complete_report


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

trackers.py

```
"""
currency_report.trackers
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This module stores data on currency exchanges, used to track rates and
their increases, decreases and stability.
"""

from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

class CurrencyTracker:
    """The data model to store data on exchange rates"""

    def __init__(self, currencies, rate):
        """Initilaises a CurrencyTracker.

        :param currencies: A tuple containing the currencies to track.
        :param rate: A tuple containing the exchange rate at the time
        of initialisation and the corresponding timestamp
        """
        self.CURRENCIES = currencies
        self.created = datetime.now()
        self.updated = datetime.now()
        self.all_time_high = rate
        self.all_time_low = rate
        self.streak = (0,0)
        self.data = [rate]

    def add_rate(self, new_rate):
        """Adds a new rate to the rate tracker and calculates streaks
        and highs.

        :param new_rate: A tuple containing the new rate and the
        timestamp associated with it.
        """

        direction, magnitude = self.streak
        high_time, high_val = self.all_time_high
        prev_time, prev_val = self.data[-1]
        rate_time, rate_val = new_rate

        if rate_val > high_val:
            self.all_time_high = new_rate
        elif rate_val < high_val:
            self.all_time_low = new_rate

        if direction > 0:
            if rate_val > prev_val:
                self.streak = (1, magnitude + 1)
            elif rate_val < prev_val:
                self.streak = (-1, 1)
            else:
                self.streak = (0,1)
        elif direction < 0:
            if rate_val < prev_val:
                self.streak = (-1, magnitude + 1)
            elif rate_val > prev_val:
                self.streak = (1, 1)
            else:
                self.streak = (0, 1)
        else:
            if rate_val == prev_val:
                self.streak = (0, magnitude + 1)
            elif rate_val > prev_val:
                self.streak = (1, 1)
            else:
                self.streak = (-1, 1)

        self.data.append(new_rate)
        self.updated = datetime.now()

    def get_current_rate(self):
        return self.data[-1]

    def get_all_time_high(self):
        return self.all_time_high

    def get_all_time_low(self):
        return self.all_time_low

    def get_streak(self):
        return self.streak

    def get_currencies(self):
        return self.CURRENCIES

    def get_created(self):
        return self.created
```

utils.py

```
"""
currency_report.utils
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This module provides utility functions that are used within currency_exchang.
"""

import pickle
import smtplib
import email.mime.text

def read_file(file_name):
    """Unpickles a file"""
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as pkl:
        return pickle.load(pkl)


def write_file(file_name, contents):
    """Pickles a file"""
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as pkl:
        pickle.dump(contents, pkl)

def send_email(subject, message, recipient, email_address, password):
    """Sends an email message via smtplib"""
    msg = email.mime.text.MIMEText(message, 'plain')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['To'] = email_address

    try:
        connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
        with connection.login(email_address, password):
            connection.sendmail(email_address, recepient, msg.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending email: {error}".format(error=str(e)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Closing file handles

Always use a context manager when reading from files, like this:

```
with open(...) as fh:
    some_var = fh.read()
```

In some places you correctly did this, but not always.

#### Method decomposition

It's very good that you decomposed your implementation to multiple functions. But you could decompose even further. For example the main function is doing too many things. You could split it further. The same is true for some of the other methods.

#### Bug?

This looks like a bug:

> ```
> if rate_val > high_val:
>     self.all_time_high = new_rate
> elif rate_val < high_val:
>     self.all_time_low = new_rate
> ```

I think the second condition should be based on the all time low, not on high val.

#### Simplify

This code sets the new direction and magnitude of a streak:

> ```
> if direction > 0:
>     if rate_val > prev_val:
>         self.streak = (1, magnitude + 1)
>     elif rate_val < prev_val:
>         self.streak = (-1, 1)
>     else:
>         self.streak = (0,1)
> elif direction < 0:
>     if rate_val < prev_val:
>         self.streak = (-1, magnitude + 1)
>     elif rate_val > prev_val:
>         self.streak = (1, 1)
>     else:
>         self.streak = (0, 1)
> else:
>     if rate_val == prev_val:
>         self.streak = (0, magnitude + 1)
>     elif rate_val > prev_val:
>         self.streak = (1, 1)
>     else:
>         self.streak = (-1, 1)
> ```

Instead of direction in the outer condition, it will be simpler and more readable to use the rate in the outer condition:

```
if rate_val == prev_val:
    new_direction = 0
elif rate_val < prev_val:
    new_direction = -1
else:
    new_direction = 1

new_magnitude = magnitude + 1 if direction == new_direction else 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
Oh yes, I see I read from the currencies.txt out of a with, thanks, I didn't catch that.


Yes you are right, that's a bug.


Oh yes, that's much more simple.


Thank you very much!